# XML Serialization - Leaving part of the XML as an XmlElement

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have an object something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
  public string AValue {get;set;}
  public XmlElement AdditionalConfig {get;set;}
}
```

I'm generating this from a block of XML that looks like:

```
<MyClass>
  <AValue>Something</AValue>
  <AdditionalConfig>
    <NewNode Att="Value" />
  </AdditionalConfig>
</MyClass>
```

If I use the XmlSerializer to de-serialize the XML then the AdditionalConfig XmlElement property is NewNode. Now, if I add a second element in there:

```
<MyClass>
  <AValue>Something</AValue>
  <AdditionalConfig>
    <NewNode Att="Value" />
    <AnotherNewNode />
  </AdditionalConfig>
</MyClass>
```

The deserialization doesn't work - it complains about an unrecognised element 'AnotherNewNode'.

I tried making MyClass.AdditionalConfig an array but no luck there. How would I get all the contents of the  node into XmlElement objects?

As always, thanks a lot

Comment: Are you trying to end up with a single node with NewNode and AnotherNewNode as children of it?

Comment: Nope, I'd like either a single XmlElement for <AdditionalConfig>, or a collection of XmlElements, in this case containing NewNode and AnotherNewNode

Its just a dumping ground for additional *stuff* but I still need to be able to read it from code - leaving it as XML seemed the best option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why that doesn't work.  However, to get the functionality you require, you can instead introduce an `AdditionalConfig` container class for your additional elements as follows:

```
public class AdditionalConfig
{
    [XmlAnyAttribute]
    public XmlAttribute[] attributes;
    [XmlAnyElement]
    public XmlElement[] elements;
}

public class MyClass
{
    public string AValue { get; set; }
    public AdditionalConfig AdditionalConfig { get; set; }
}
```

[`[XmlAnyElement]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute.aspx) when applied to an array of `XmlElement` or `XElement` types captures any and all unknown elements in the XML to be deserialized.  Similarly [`[XmlAnyAttribute]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyattributeattribute.aspx), if needed, captures unknown attributes of the `<AdditionalConfig>` element into an `XmlAttribute` array.

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HU3aid).

Comment: Lovely! I'd started messing about with IXmlSerializable but this is much nicer :)