# How to prevent XmlSerialzer from escaping "nested XML"?

Tags: c#, xml, escaping, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I am using an XmlSerializer to serialize / deserialize complex objects. One property contains an XML string that should be written into a string property without deserialization.

**Example (executable in LinqPad):**

```
[XmlRoot("RootObject")]
[Serializable]
public class RootClass
{
    [XmlArray("SubObjects")]
    [XmlArrayItem("SubObject")]
    public SubClass[] SubObjecs { get; set;} 
}

[Serializable]
public class SubClass
{
    [XmlElement("XmlConfiguration")]
    public string XmlConfiguration { get; set;}
}

void Main()
{
    var obj = new RootClass()
    {
        SubObjecs = new[]
        {
            new SubClass { XmlConfiguration = "<ConfigurationX>SomeConfiguration1</ConfigurationX>" },
            new SubClass { XmlConfiguration = "<ConfigurationY>SomeConfiguration2</ConfigurationY>" }
        }
    };

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootClass));
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(stream, obj);
        stream.Position = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.GetBuffer()));
    }
}
```

The output of the example is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RootObject xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <SubObjects>
        <SubObject>
            <XmlConfiguration>&lt;ConfigurationX&gt;SomeConfiguration1&lt;/ConfigurationX&gt;</XmlConfiguration>
        </SubObject>
        <SubObject>
            <XmlConfiguration>&lt;ConfigurationY&gt;SomeConfiguration2&lt;/ConfigurationY&gt;</XmlConfiguration>
        </SubObject>
    </SubObjects>
</RootObject>
```

The XML is a configuration file that is sometimes written programmatically,  but mainly written / modified by humans. Therefore the XML within `XmlConfiguration` should not contain escaped characters.

**Question:** 
Is it possible to prevent the XmlSerializer from escaping the '<' and '>' characters? If not, Is there another serializer that can be used?

One option that works is [XmlWriter.WriteRaw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/8563xyxa(v=vs.110).aspx). However, if somehow possible I would avoid that unreliable and less maintainable solution.

---

I found a similar question here: [How to prevent XmlSerializer from escaping < and > characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030591/how-to-prevent-xmlserializer-from-escaping-and-characters). But that question is related to !CDATA[[Content]] and has no answer for my problem.

Comment: You can use `[XmlAnyElement]` and `[XmlAnyAttribute]` on a nested `XmlConfiguration` class.  See [XML Serialization - Leaving part of the XML as an XmlElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36774451/xml-serialization-leaving-part-of-the-xml-as-an-xmlelement).

Comment: Incidentally, if you prefer LINQ-to-XML to the old `XmlDocument`, then a `List<XElement>` will work with `XmlAnyElement` (though a `List<XAttribute>` will not work with `[XmlAnyAttribute]`, strangely.)  See for instance [Deserialize dynamic XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555278/deserialize-dynamic-xml).

Comment: @dbc: Nice, Thanks! It is also possible to use `[XmlAnyElement]` in combination with `XElement` (without List). Do you want to write your comments as answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned above in comment by dbc, there is a solution that uses the `XmlAnyElement` attribute as described here: [Deserialize dynamic XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555278/deserialize-dynamic-xml)

---

I found a solution that is a mixture of `XmlSerializer` and `XmlWriter.WriteRaw`. When implementing `IXmlSerializable`, it is possible to control the serialization process of the `XmlSerializer`. Therfore IXmlSerializable has to be implemented just for the class that needs special handling (which is OK for me):

```
[Serializable]
public class SubClass : IXmlSerializable
{
    [XmlElement("XmlConfiguration")]
    public string XmlConfiguration { get; set; }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("XmlConfiguration");
        writer.WriteRaw(XmlConfiguration);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.ReadToDescendant("XmlConfiguration");
        XmlConfiguration = reader.ReadInnerXml();
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return (null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need CDATA encapsulation you can use [XmlCDataSection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlcdatasection?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) for this. You following class as type of your xml element. You can change names or attributes as you need it for every different type of element.

```
public class XmlConfiguration //Or any other class name.
    {
        [XmlAttribute("attr1")]
        public string Attr1 { get; set; } //You don't need this but use if you need attribute.

        [XmlAttribute("attr2")]
        public string Attr2 { get; set; } //Or second one.

        [XmlIgnore]
        public string Content { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public XmlNode[] CDataContent
        {
            get
            {
                var dummy = new XmlDocument();
                return new XmlNode[] {dummy.CreateCDataSection(Content)};
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == null)
                {
                    Content = null;
                    return;
                }

                if (value.Length != 1)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(
                        String.Format(
                            "Invalid array length {0}", value.Length));
                }

                var node0 = value[0];
                var cdata = node0 as XmlCDataSection;
                if (cdata == null)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(
                        String.Format(
                            "Invalid node type {0}", node0.NodeType));
                }

                Content = cdata.Data;
            }
        }
    }
```

I found this answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6f59a2c0-2f70-4f19-9210-c675bbdce48d/cdata-serialization-with-xmlserializer?forum=asmxandxml). Check the link for complete discussion.